# Linux Equivalent for a windows Batch Script

Tags: linux, batch

i just switched over from windows to ubuntu. and i had a batch file to clean up unwanted files from certain downloads. and then clean up the empty folders. what would be the linux equivalent for the following.

```
for /R "Z:\Downloads\torrent\DONE" %%G in (*.txt *.jpg *.nfo *.exe *sample* *.sample* *-sample* ) do DEL "%%G"
for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%d"
```

i would ideally like to make a .sh or a .py for it.

Comment: Why don't you try read up on how Bash (the most common "cmd.exe" for Linux) works, and make an attempt to write up something similar? www.tldp.org has a couple of Guides on Bash that tell you a lot of detail how it all works. And you know; superuser is not a script writing service. Welcome back when you've made an attempt.

Comment: The easiest way is to not throw around commands and flags but rather to use the “prose” description: Delete some files in some folder, delete some folders. Also note that folders are usually referred to as _directories_ on Linux.

Comment: there's kind of a prose description in the intro paragraph,  but yeah more details would help.

Comment: find(3) can probably do what you want.